# Ngnix downloading php

Tags: nginx, devops

I am trying to get nginx to route all requests starting with /embed to `/home/forge/dev.tline.io/embed/index.php`

My Nginx config:

```
location /embed {
    root   /home/forge/dev.tline.io;
    try_files /embed/index.php =404;
}

location / {
    root   /home/forge/dev.tline.io;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

All requests go to `/embed/index.php` but it doesn't run the php file it downloads it.

Note: `http://dev.tline.io/embed/index.php` is compiled not downloaded

I got it to work if add

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
```

into `location /embed` but there should be a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the following code,

```
map $request_uri $rot {
   "~ /embed" /home/forge/dev.tline.io/embed/;
   default /home/forge/dev.tline.io/;
}
map $request_uri $ind {
   "~ /embed" index.php;
   default index.html;
}
server {
   ...
   root $rot;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   ...
   location / {
       try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /$ind =404;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
   ...
}
```

If this doesn't work out, try switching `$ind` position suitably, and check error log in case of extra '/' found.

Comment: I have removed the `root` from inside the `location` but it hasn't changed anything, i already had a `root` definition outside the `location`

Comment: did you put try_files in php location block?

Comment: i added that as well, didn't work.
If i add the php location code into the /embed block it works, but its an ugly solution

Answer (score 0):

This should execute /embed/index.php for all /embed URLs:

```
server {
  root /home/forge/dev.tline.io;

  location / {
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /embed {
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME  $document_root/embed/index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/embed/index.php;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: i want all calls to /embed/anything to run /embed/index.php
anything else i want to use the default location block

Comment: I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: why isn't it internally redirecting into the `location ~ \.php$` block?
why do i have to add the `fastcgi_params` into the `/embed` block?

Comment: That is not how Nginx works - only the location block which matches the URL best is called, there is no automatic redirecting after that. You could do a rewrite in /embed - but why do you want to have a `location ~ \.php$` block anyway? If index.php should be called for all /embed URLs then my solution is exactly what you want, because it is explicit and easy to understand. I tend to avoid something like `location ~ \.php$` - this makes every .php file in every directory below the root directory executeable by PHP, which is usually not necessary and can pose risks.